# Inserting elements in a linked list in a sorted way

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

- I am trying to add int elements to my single linked list in a sorted manner. but the output is coming in a random order. Can anyone please suggest me what is wrong with my code?

This is my Node.java class where I am using Generics

```
/* Node.java */
public class Node<E>{
    private E info;
    private Node<E> next;

    public Node(){
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node(E info){
        this.info = info;
        this.next = null;
    }
    public Node(E info, Node<E> next){
        this.info = info;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public E getInfo(){
        return this.info;
    }
    public void setInfo(E info){
        this.info = info;
    }
    public Node<E> getNext(){
        return this.next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<E> next){
        this.next = next;
    }

}
```

In the main method, I created a linked list and using Math.random() method - I am trying to insert int elements to my linked list

```
/* Main Method */

public class SortedInsertionLinkedList{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        // Create a linked list using MyLinkedList<Integer>
        MyLinkedList<Integer> mine = new MyLinkedList<Integer>();
       // Insert 10 ints 
        for (int i=0; i< 10; i++){
            mine.insert((int)(100*Math.random()));
        }
        
        //Print the whole list
        mine.print();
    }
}
```

In the implementation of linked list, I am using compareTo() method

```
/* Linked list implementation */

public class MyLinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>>{
   
    private Node<E> first;
    
    public MyLinkedList(){
        this.first = null;
    }
    
       public void insert(E info){
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(info);
        
        if(first == null || info.compareTo(first.getInfo()) < 0 ) {
            newNode.setNext(first);
            first = newNode;
        } else {
            Node<E> current = first;
            while(current.getNext() != null && info.compareTo(current.getNext().getInfo()) < 0)
            {
                current = current.getNext();
                
            }
            newNode.setNext(current.getNext());
            current.setNext(newNode); 
        }
        }
        
    
    public void print(){
        Node<E> current = first;
        
        while (current != null){
            System.out.print(current.getInfo() + " ");
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the driver code with an example of insertions, demonstrating the problem?

Comment: public static void main(String args[]){
      
     MyLinkedList<Integer> mine = new MyLinkedList<Integer>();
    
     for (int i=0; i< 10; i++){
         mine.insert((int)(100*Math.random()));
     }
     
    
     mine.print();
    }

Comment: Above is my main method, where I am using Math.random() to generate the integers and trying to insert them into linked list

Comment: Can you edit your question and add this code in a formatted way? Add enough code for us to reproduce the issue. So please add your Node class code as well.

Comment: Sound like you need to check your "info.compareTo" method. If the input number is between (1-9) my guesses is that you may get consistent output. Coming to strings, or beyond 10 and it gets inconsistent then, most probably the comparator used is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your while statement needs to be `while(current.getNext() != null && info.compareTo(current.getNext().getInfo()) > 0)`. I'd recommend running through the algorithm on paper with a few test numbers - for example, inserting 1 into [2,5], inserting 3 into [2,5], and inserting 6 into [2,5]. You might also want to test the case of duplicates such as inserting 2 into [1,2,2,3]. `info.compareTo(current.getNext().getInfo())` returns something less than 0 if `info` is less than `current.getNext().getInfo()` and something greater than 0 if `info` is greater than `current.getNext().getInfo()`. It returns 0 if the two values are equal.